# elliptic curve infinity point implementation returns exception

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to implement an elliptic curve discret logarithm problem, but I have got a problem due to the representation of the infinity point. I tried this code :

first define what is an infinity point

```
    public Point infinity() {
        BigInteger xInfinity = new BigDecimal(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).toBigInteger();
        BigInteger yInfinity = new BigDecimal(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).toBigInteger();

        return new Point(xInfinity, yInfinity, this.E);
    }
```

then to test if a given point is an infinity point to return the same point when adding to it

```
public boolean isInfinity() {
    if (this.x == new BigDecimal(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).toBigInteger()
            || this.y == new BigDecimal(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).toBigInteger()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but I still get an exception even if i try to calculate with simple points

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN

Thanks to help me solving this.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, because it asks about debugging (cryptographic / math) code rather than asking about Cryptography itself. Normally I would have migrated this question to StackOverflow, because it seems to be decent enough to be well-received there (which is why I wrote an answer), however migration failed due to issues with your stackoverflow account. I have thus closed it with our custom reason instead.

Answer (score 1):

So to understand why the code doesn't work, we need a bit of background on [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point representation of which `BigDecimal` is essentially an arbitrary precision extension. Most notably it defines special values to indicate a computation yielded "infinity" (which is the `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` you are using) and for computations that yielded an invalid result (such as `log(0)` or `1/0`), this is called "NotANumber" (NaN). So what BigDecimal does, is that it is essentially a `double` with higher precision, but using similar values for these special cases.

Now `BigInteger` on the other hand, is an extension of the usual `int` to arbitrary precision, taking up as many bits as needed to represent the number at hand. As it is an extension of `int`, this also means that it doesn't support special values such as "infinity" or "NaN", but rather only actually representable integers.

When you do `new BigDecimal(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).toBigInteger()`, you create a new `BigDecimal` with the special "infinity" value / flag and try to convert this to an "ordinary" integer. But as you can't represent infinity with an integer, as this would need an infinite amount of storage, an exception is thrown instead.

Now, how can you fix this? Well, this is actually a non-trivial question and depends on what you want to do with the points. If you want to do elliptic curve cryptography using affine coordinates (which is terribly inefficient), then the usual approach is to give your `Point` a flag which essentially indicates "infinity" and test for the flag when you implement doubling and addition. When you use a more modern curve which has a complete addition law (that is it works for all points), then there are specific, concrete coordinates defined for the point at infinity. Of course the best solution would be to use projective coordinates, which can represent the point at infinity perfectly easy using a `Z` coordinate of `0`.